# PyTorch reinstall fails when trying to fix TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA runtime error

Tags: python, pytorch

When trying to run an LLM program that takes a user input and generates a set of characters, I get this error:

`For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Compile with 'TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA' to enable device-side assertions.`

upon runtime.

I have tried to reinstall pytorch  using `install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --force-reinstall --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu118` however this doesn't work as I am haven't got a version that satisfies the torchvision requirement

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision`

I have reinstalled torch without torchvision and torchaudio but the error message persists.

Comment: Welcome! What is your python version?

Comment: I'm running python 3.11.5